# In C, how do you access elements in this struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

How do I access elements in this stuct if I initialize a list as follows:

```
group **list = (group **) malloc(sizeof(group)); 

typedef struct
{
    // ID of the group, 'A' to 'D'
    char id;

    // a list of members in the group 
    char **members;
} group;
```

I tried using `(*list)->id = 'A'` and it compiles but then gets a segmentation fault error when running the program.

Comment: Hmm - why are you casting that malloc pointer to a `group **` instead of a `group *`?

Comment: You shouldn't be casting the result of malloc *at all*.

Comment: @SamDufel: I want to initialize a pointer to a list that points to a malloc'ed array of pointers to group struct.

Comment: @PaulR: I cast it to make it compatible with C++, but even if I don't cast it, I still can't access the elements in group struct :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it compiles fine, you didn't allocate memory correctly.

You allocated memory for `group **list`, which is eventually an array of pointers to struct `group`. What I think you *intended* to do doing is:

```
group** list = malloc(sizeof(group*) * 5);  // e.g. 5 pointers
```

Now for each pointer in the array, allocate its own memory:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list[i] = malloc(sizeof(group));
}
```

For instance, to access `id` in the 2nd struct, you do:

```
list[1]->id = 'A';
```

Note that `*list` access the *first* struct, and is equivalent to `list[0]`.

**Sidenote:**
Two levels of indirection allow you to store the structs in a non-continuous way in the memory. Alternatively, you can use one level of indirection and store them continuously:

```
group list* = malloc(sizeof(group) * 5);  // Again, 5 structs
```

and then access the members with:

```
list[0].id = 'A';
```

Answer (score 5):

```
struct group
{
    // ID of the group, 'A' to 'D'
    char id;

    // a list of members in the group 
    char **members;
};

//this initializes one group
group *a_group = malloc(sizeof(struct group)); //cast not needed in C

//this initializes an array of 10 group
group **list = malloc(sizeof(struct group *) * 10);

//initialize each one of the 10
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
  list[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct group));
}

//get something out of group
a_group->id;

//get first group out of list
list[0]->id;
*list->id;

// 10 elements continuous memory
group *array_of_groups = malloc(sizeof(struct group) * 10);
array_of_groups[0].id;
*array_of_groups.id;
```

Comment: Isn't that double allocating the memory?  My C is rusty, but shouldn't you be doing `group **list = malloc(sizeof(group *) * 10)` ?

Comment: -1 for providing an answer with so many compilation errors. What's `group[0]` or `*group` in the last lines? You forgot the `struct` keyword in the `malloc`. You're not using `list` like the OP intended.

Comment: @EitanT Ok next time i'll write pseudo next to it. Anyway, is it better now?

Comment: @EitanT He typedefed it. But i'll do it just for making it clear.

Comment: @sam Yes. fixed that. And added example for case.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind the double-indirection pointer is just a pointer to a *list* that happens to point to the first entry by default. You need to allocate for the individual entry/entries, not just the list pointer (**list), some flavor of the following:

```
//rough code, not tested... std caveats apply :)
group *one_group = malloc(sizeof(group));

list[0]=one_group;
list[0]->id = 'A'; // or one_group->id='A';
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets say i have to make a **list of pointers**. members of this list each points to a **memory chunk** mapped by type group.

now lets say i have 10 items,

so:

```
group *tmp = malloc(sizeof(group) * 10);
```

now tmp is pointing to the start of these chunks.

Now i want to to make a list of pointers, where every item in the list points to a chunk.

lets create 10 pointers,

```
group ** list = malloc(sizeof(group *) * 10)
```

now initialize this list of of pointers:

```
i = 10;
while(i--) {
    list++ = &(tmp++);
}
```

Now your list is initialized with pointers to chunks. One problem remained, your list is pointing to the last. If you don't want that

```
list-= 10;
```

Now you want to retrieve something from the list :

```
while(i--) {
    printf("%c\n", (*(list++))->a);
}
```

But this kind of list management is weird and not to mention error prone. you should seriously think about maintaining your list through "LINKED LIST". a trivial scenario like you have given can be easily implemented through a singly linked list.

Comment: This is a very non-intuitive way of initializing a list to pointers to structs.

Comment: The most intuitive way to create list of pointers is through "linked list". The approach taken by this question is already "non intuitive". What we are trying to do is to find a semantically correct answer. But all of our approaches are aesthetically bad, not mention will be good source of future bugs.

Comment: No, not if you want O(1) complexity for accessing members. It's perfectly legitimate to create an array of pointers to structs. I just said that _your_ way of doing that is counter-intuitive.

Comment: Can't you just set it up as an array?  `group * list = malloc(sizeof(group) * 10); list[0]->id = 'A'` ?

Comment: @SamDufel Yeah, I think that in this case you should (the array of pointers is indeed pointless here).

Comment: its my personal opinion, i prefer pointer arithmetic over array indexing. array indexing is just a shorthand for pointer arithmetic. compiler translates array indexing into appropriate pointer arithmetic anyway. Another thing is, in a practical situations, your structs will become longer and more complex. that way linked allocation is the way to go. C gives a cheap way to manipulate pointers, why not use it with its full glory? again its my personal opinion, its how i feel about arrays.

Comment: @SamDufel using arrays of pointers in this situation is a overkill. But there are situation when you want to represent more complex data items, then, just a lone pointer to a contiguous chunk of memory is not enough.